# PLSQL Insufficient Privileges While disabling a trigger from another schema

Tags: database, plsql, triggers, plsqldeveloper

I know this sounds weird but it's an old project that I'm trying to make work.

I have two schemas SchemaA and SchemaB each one with it's own user.

I'm writing a plsql script in a package in SchemaB, but in this script I need to delete records from a table in SchemaA. But there is a trigger that won't let the delete happen.

So to make it work I have to do this command:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER SchemaA.TDA_K$TriggerA DISABLE';
```

But when I do that I get ORA-01031 which is logical since SchemaB cannot disable a trigger From SchemaA

My question is, how can I GRANT the permission on the trigger (or table utilizing that trigger), to SchemaB to be able to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Oracle documentation
" **Prerequisites**

The trigger must be in your own schema or you must have ALTER ANY TRIGGER system privilege.

In addition, to alter a trigger on DATABASE, you must have the ADMINISTER database events system privilege.

"